# CoreData find string - NSPredicate OR for loop?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data

Sorry for my bad English, I'm beginner of using CoreData.

Now I'm trying to find if a NSString does exist in database,

there are two ways to do that, one is using NSPredicate to do request,

if `results` array count >= 1, means did find something in database

```
[fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"itemid == %@", self.item.itemid]];
 NSError *error = nil;
 NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

and another is to do loop in array

```
 for (int i=0; i<=[keyArray count]-1 ; i++) {
            NSString *keyID = [keyArray objectAtIndex:i];
            if ([keyID isEqual:stringToCompare])
                return YES;
                break;
    return NO;
 }
```

I'm using the first method now, but can somebody give me some advice?

which one would be the best for performance?
thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Speed: iOS Using NSPredicate filterUsingPredicate vs. for loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17887919/speed-ios-using-nspredicate-filterusingpredicate-vs-for-loop)

Comment: This is **NOT** a duplicate of [Speed: iOS Using NSPredicate filterUsingPredicate vs. for loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17887919/speed-ios-using-nspredicate-filterusingpredicate-vs-for-loop), because *this* question is about a Core Data fetch request, and *that* question is only about filtering an NSArray.

Answer (score 2):

Your second methods (array loop) requires that *all objects* are fetched from the data base,
so that should be slower than the first method, which fetches only the matching objects.

You can even improve the first method if you are only interested in the *existence*
of an object with the given key, by limiting the result set to one object, and using 
`countForFetchRequest` instead of actually fetching the objects:

```
[fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"itemid == %@", self.item.itemid]];
[fetchRequest setFetchLimit:1];
NSUInteger count = [context countForFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
if (count == NSNotFound)
    // some error occurred
else if (count == 0)
    // no matching object
else
    // at least one matching object exists
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can't say which method is best because it depends on many factors. For example, how many data in the sqlite database? If you are able to confirm the data size, you can perform a simple load test. Create dummy data in sqlite and array, then use both method to find how long do they need. If data size is too large, I suggest you use sqlite instead of array loop.